# Azure b2c custom policy, LinkedIn Identity Provider, unable to get email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, linkedin-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to add LinkedIn as an identity provider to my azure b2c tenant.

I have already added Microsoft and Google as id providers.

However, when I added LinkedIn, it was impossible to retrieve an email address and put it in the azure b2c token.
Here is my custom policy base file: TrustFrameworkBase.xml

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>linkedin.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LinkedIn-OAuth2">
      <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">linkedin</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">r_emailaddress r_liteprofile</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="external_user_identity_claim_id">id</Item>
        <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
        <Item Key="ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens">true</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">MyLinkedInClientId</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_LinkedInSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName.localized" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName.localized" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="linkedin.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractGivenNameFromLinkedInResponse" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractSurNameFromLinkedInResponse" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

As we can see, the ClaimsEndPoint is `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`
But, this end point does not give access to the email address.
Here is the documentation detailing it:
[Sign-in with linked-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin)

We see that to get the email address, we need to call another end point: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`

I tried changing the ClaimsEndPoint to this but when uploading the custom policy, I got an error:

> The policy being uploaded is not correctly formatted: '=' is an unexpected token.

I don't see what I could do to get the email address as a claim in the azure b2c token.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-linkedin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#obtain-an-email-address), you need to make an additional API call and pass the access token you already have.